# How to add an image multi array to an JLabel multi array to Box

Tags: java, swing, boxlayout

What is the best way to add a JLabel[][] to Box?

I am making an `Image[][]` and I want to add each element of this image array to `JLabel[][]`. I can do this. But I want to add `JLabel[][]` to Box. I use Box to hold all my java components such as `JPanel`, `JButton` etc. But when I try to add `JLabel[][]` to the Box, it doesn't allow it. Would it be safe to use `JPanel[][]` or some other component?

```
anyBox.add(JLabel[][]);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, Box is the java class Box. from javax.swing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying add an array of object into a method that does not allow this, and by trying this, you're breaking some basic Java rules -- the main one being that you're making up methods that don't exist. Instead you have to use the methods that are available to you and pass in the types of objects allowed. A container such as a JPanel will allow you to add other components into it, and so this is what you should do. Give it a decent layout, perhaps a GridLayout, and use a for loop to add your components into it, one at a time.

Note, that if you're trying to add a grid of components, then don't use a Box object as it forces you to use a BoxLayout, which is not appropriate to your needs. Use a JPanel with a GridLayout or GridBagLayout or MigLayout or any layout that more readily displays a grid of components.

Comment: Ok I will try GridBagLayout. I've never had to use GridBagLayout but it seems like the this would be the appropriate measure for this. Thanks!

Comment: @Iron: I suggest that you first that you don't want to use the much simpler and easy to use `GridLayout`. The `GridBagLayout` is one of the more difficult layout managers out there with quite a few traps and "gotchas".